# Two installations of Chrome with different download notification styles?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, download, notifications

I have Chrome installed on two different Windows 10 laptops. The laptops are identical - same hardware, same Windows version, and same Chrome version (all up to date).

A couple of months ago one of the Chrome installations suddenly replaced the download bar at the bottom of the window with a brief popup anchored to the top right where the extension icons are.  I much prefer this to the download bar, but I cannot figure out what change was made, as it seems to have been automatic. I did nothing to cause the change.

I'd love for my other installation to function this way.  I spent an hour searching the web and found nothing that refers to this, but I could have missed it.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots? Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Do you have exactly the same extensions on both Chrome setups ?